# Breakpoints set in inner class don't stop in IntelliJ community 2016.2

Tags: intellij-idea

I'm doing remote Java app debugging using IntelliJ community ed 2016.2. I have a class with an inner class. For some reason, the breakpoints set within a method of the inner class don’t stop but the lines are executed (breakpoints set in a method of outer class are fine). The breakpoints are shown with an icon of orange color solid circle. I read JetBrains help page, and it says that icon stands for break point enabled but yet to be loaded into debugger. Does anyone know what possible reasons those break points may not get loaded into debugger after debugging session started? Below is the screenshot of debug session.

[image]

I also verified with javap -l to see if debugging info generated for inner class. And yes:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! [Please don't post your code as an image.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3933332)

Comment: Are you sure that the code in your editor is exactly matching the compiled code in the remote app?